# Is Factory Method pattern without abstract methods possible?

Tags: java, abstract, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

Let's say one Java program that does not have abstract methods, is it possible to implement the Factory Method pattern without abstract methods?

Comment: yes, what concerns you ?

Comment: Just a note. Factory method is different from factory design pattern

Comment: have a look http://java.dzone.com/articles/factory-method-pattern-java, may be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely: a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) does not need to be an abstract one - it could be a non-abstract method with a default implementation throwing an exception, or it could be a method of an interface, which is always abstract.

```
interface Product {
    void doSomething();
}
interface Creator {
     Product create(String someData);
}
class ProductX implements Product {
    public void doSomething() {
         System.out.println("X");
    }
}
class ProductY implements Product {
    public void doSomething() {
         System.out.println("y");
    }
}
class XYFactory implements Creator {
    public Product create(String someData) {
        if ("X".equals(someData)) {
            return new ProductX();
        }
        if ("Y".equals(someData)) {
            return new ProductY();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to implement the Factory method pattern without them though.

Comment: @Minhaj Take a look at a small example that I added to the answer.